# An exception is encountered java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec

Tags: java, spring, unix

Anyone knows what is the reason for encountering this exception?

An exception is encountered during the processing. The stack track is below:

```
java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:451)
java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:464)

....

org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:248)
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:198)
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:90)
org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
```

Comment: Did the exception have a message? Just the stack trace isn't terribly helpful, but I'd expect the message to be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is being thrown from the `start()` method, then the OS isn't able to fork/exec the process. So the problem isn't the subprocess dying, but that it's not being launched.

So are you specifying this correctly ? Are you relying on `PATH` settings ? Are the execute permissions correct ?

It would be useful to see the code that you use to initialise the `ProcessBuilder`. i.e. the invocation parameters.